# Confusing output when calcualting md5 hash (newbie)

Tags: c++, md5

On my linux-machine, in order to authenticate on a socket, I have to calculate an md5 hashcode. (I know md5 is outdated). After installing Openssl, I can compile this code in Eclipse:

```
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n,
             unsigned char *md);

string codewd = "admin:BaseX:admin";
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char md5_pwd[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// Test 1
const unsigned char* str;
str = (unsigned char*)"Hallooo";
unsigned int long_size = 100;
for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(result); i++) result[i] = '\0';
MD5(str, long_size, result);
cout << "Result : " << result << endl;

// Test 2
string nonce = "25009293498380";
const unsigned char * code = (const unsigned char *)codewd.c_str();
for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(md5_pwd); i++) md5_pwd[i] = '\0';
MD5((const unsigned char *) code, long_size, md5_pwd);
cout << "md5_pwd : " << md5_pwd << endl;
```

This code gives this output:

```
Result : Y����P2KT�L����
md5_pwd : �?�a'=����Y��aOY����P2KT�L����
```

I don't know if it is necessary to initialize 'result' and 'md5_pwd'. The 'nonce' will be used at a later moment.

I have two problems:

1. Every run on this code gives different output. I would expect that calculating a md5 hash would give the same result every time.
2. Why is the first hash (calculated for 'result') appended to the second hash?

Ben

Comment: `MD5` does not output a string of printable characters, it outputs a 128-bit hash value. If you want to output it to the screen, you need to transform binary to a printable representation. I understand how this can be confusing because pure binary data is the same datatype as many string types (`unsigned char*`)

Comment: I am not interested  in the output as such, output is only created for testing. And the test shows that every run gives different results and that the first result is appended to the second. That is the problem

Answer (score 2):

> Every run on this code gives different output.

You pass `long_size` to the `MD5` function but the length of the input string is not `long_size`, so the algorithm reads a bunch of garbage.

Try this:

```
MD5(str, strlen(str), result);
```

> Why is the first hash (calculated for 'result') appended to the second hash?

`md5_pwd` doesn't contain a terminating null so the memory contents past the allocated array are printed. Print with:

```
cout.write(md5_pwd, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

Comment: According to the signature for MD5, the first parameter should be `const unsigned char *d`. Compiling strlen(str) results in `invalid conversion from ‘const unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’`.

Comment: It's because `strlen` takes a `const char*`. I would leave `"Hallooo"` as `const char*` or `const char[]` and only cast it when passed to `MD5`.

Comment: After the cast my code compiles but I stil get this ouput in which the result from the first MD5() is appended to the second MD5().
    Result : (�Ј`�Ooy�k<b`ΰ�
    md5_pwd : 0K߰8<�p����\�(�Ј`�Ooy�k<b`ΰ�

Comment: After adding a cast "cout.write((const char *)md5_pwd, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);" everything works fine. Thanx for the explanation